# How to add line-break/new line in kendo ui custom toolbar

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, kendo-ui

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ModelVM>()
.Name("ModelVM")
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "padding: 0px; margin: 0px;height:100% "     })
.ToolBar(toolbar =>
{
    toolbar.Custom()
        .Text("First").HtmlAttributes(new { id = "someid" })
        .Action("Index2", "Home");
    toolbar.Custom()
        .Text("Second")
        .Action("Index2", "Home");
    toolbar.Custom()
        .Text("Third")
        .Action("Index3", "Home");
    toolbar.Custom()
        .Text("Fourth")
        .Action("Index4", "Home");
    toolbar.Custom()
        .Text("Fifth")
        .Action("Index5", "Home");
    toolbar.Custom()
        .Text("Sixth")
        .Action("Index6", "Home");
    .
    .
    .       
} )
```

I am struck in simple problem. Sorry if it is too simple. 
My question is I want "sixth" custom tool bar should come in new line. How to do that?
OR How to insert line break/new line in Kendo-UI tool bar. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this and apply any style you want, by using HTML markup.

```
.ToolBar(toolbar =>
{
    toolbar.Template(@<text>
        <div class="toolbar">
            <a href="Index">Index</a> <p>
            <a href="Index2">Index2</a> <p>
            <a href="Index3">Index3</a> <p>
            ...
        </div>
    </text>);
})
```

Comment: if I add this code after fifth elements.    toolbar.Template(@<text><div class="toolbar"><br/></div></text>); Entire toolbar disappears. Except whatever I add inside <div></div>. Can you throw some more light here. Anyways thanks for help.

Comment: My question is how I can use toolbar.Template with the problem I presented. If I use toolbar.template inside previous code. Previous code doesn't work.

Comment: @SushilGupta, no, you don't add that after the fifth element, you replace what you have with that and between the `text` tags you place whatever you want: your links to the actions, for example. I will edit my answer shortly

Comment: Didn't try yet. But seems like it will work. thanks.